# Implementing facebook type notifications in chat window above online users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an admin section in my website (asp.net C#) in which the person should get notification  about the various operations like insert update etc taking place on the Db.

I want to get notified when a particular user does something like adds new data.

How can I implement this in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This is not a homework site. You should show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Within SQL you can have triggers that run on changes, but outside of that you're looking at polling (using a service or the website itself caching the index of the last record and looking to see if another id has been inserted).

Some how store the "last inserted id" for a table then check (assuming an INT key):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  id > @LastObservedIndex;
```

That would return any new entries from the last time you checked. then, of course, if new entries are found you'll need to update your cached id so the next call checks for more new entries.

I do recommend you making this a service or a scheduled task though; that is to say you don't want every admin making queries checking for new entries on every page visit. You can then store the events in a message queue and dump new notifications to the user when they visit the page (or poll using AJAX).

Alternatively, if you're handling all of the CRUD operations (your site is doing any and all updating and not working with some other outside process) you could place logging/tracking code in your repository. e.g.:

```
public class MessageRepository : IMessageRepository<Message>
{
  //
  // ...
  //

  void Add(Message message)
  {
    //
    // add to database code
    //

    // some logging utility that's tracking transactions against specific
    // database elements and reporting them back to some notification log
    // that can then be output to the admin
    this.LogTransaction<Message>(message, TransactionType.Create); 
  }
}
```

However, this, of course, comes with its own overhead.